# How do I see the json data stored in the collections in mysql. it just shows the binary when I check in mysql workbench.?

Tags: mysql, json

How do I see the json data stored in the collections in mysql. it just shows the binary when I check in mysql workbench.?? Am I missing something or some other tool to be used.
It is handy you are developing to see the data in the collection. It help troubleshoot much faster.

I tried using mysql workbench, but that does not show the data.

Comment: JSON is binary datatype. You'd convert it to string explicitly, for example ```SELECT CAST(json_column AS CHAR) AS json_as_string, ..```.

Comment: @Akina That isn't normally needed. It's stored in binary, but converted to a JSON string when you select it.

Comment: @Barmar Depends on the client. https://dbfiddle.uk/d_cRrYr6 *but converted to a JSON string when you select it* it is converted to BLOB, not to TEXT...

Comment: @Akina -- This seems differ between versions and between the commandline "mysql" tool and other access methods.

Comment: @Barmar - See my comment above;

Comment: And maybe between MySQL and MariaDB.  And I think the underlying type is `LONGTEXT` with `utf8mb4`.

Comment: @RickJames *And maybe between MySQL and MariaDB* 100%. MariaDB implements JSON functions but not JSON datatype (which is an alias for LONGTEXT simply).